# Symfony: problem with dynamically modified forms

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I've got theses 2 dropdown selects:

- first one with Types of services
- second one with services
  Type is a property of Service and Service has a onetomany relation with Solution
  When you select a type, 2nd select is filled (Ajax) with Services concerned by Type selected. Then a submit button would show the Solutions for the selected service (this "submit part is not yet implemented")
  I followed the [symfony doc tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) to do this but my 2nd dropdown just disappear when I'm choosing a type in 1 st select

Here's mySolutionsChooseType.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Service;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class SolutionsChooseType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{

    $types = [
        "Conception et développement d'applications" => "Conception et développement d'applications",
        "Conseil et prestations en architecture des infrastructures et systèmes d'informations" =>
        "Conseil et prestations en architecture des infrastructures et systèmes d'informations",
        "Fourniture et maintenance d'applications bureautiques" => "Fourniture et maintenance d'applications bureautiques",
        "Hébergement, maintenance et diffusion d'applications métiers" => "Hébergement, maintenance et diffusion d'applications métiers",
        "Sécurité informatique" => "Sécurité informatique",
        "Services informatiques" => "Services informatiques",
        "Services collaboratifs" => "Services collaboratifs",
        "Services de communications" => "Services de communications",
        "Stockage centralisé et sécurisé de données" => "Stockage centralisé et sécurisé de données",
        "Support transversal" => "Support transversal",
    ];

    $builder
        ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez un type de service',
            'choices' => $types,
        ]);
    };
}
```

if anyone can help. Thanks by advance.

My twig view with js code inside, for information:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
Liste des Solutions par Service (et par Type)
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Liste des Solutions</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <h2>Voici la liste des solutions, groupées par Type de Service:</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-lg">
                {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'solutions_choose'} }) }}    
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        Ajouter une solution&nbsp;
                        <a href="{{ path('solution_create') }}">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                        </a>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
                    
        var type = $('#solutions_choose_type');
        type.change(function () {
            
            
            var data = $('#solutions_choose_type option:selected').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:  '/solution/ajax',
                type: 'POST',
                //type: form.attr('method'),
                data: {"type": data},
                success: function (html) {
                    // Replace current position field ...
                    $('#solutions_choose_services').replaceWith(
                        // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                        $(html.responseText).find('#solutions_choose_services')
                        // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
                    )
                }
            });
            //alert (form.attr('action'));
            console.log(data);
            //console.log(form);
        });

        });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

selected type is correctly passed by variable data (I can see it by console.log(data); )

My SolutionController.php:

```
class SolutionController extends AbstractController
{

/**
 * @Route("/ajax", name="ajax")
 * 
 */
public function UpdateSolutions(ServiceRepository $servrepo, Request $request): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(SolutionsChooseType::class);
    $type = $request->request->get('type');
    // dd($type);
    $services = $servrepo->findBy([
        'Type' => $type,
    ]);
    $form->add('services', ChoiceType::class, [
        'placeholder'   => 'Choisir un service',
        'choices'       => $services,
    ]);
    return $this->renderForm("solution/SolutionsAll.html.twig", [
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `line 33:         function (FormEvent $event, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)` Where is the function name ????

Answer (score 0):

There are several parts to this.

Let's start with the controller:

The `createForm()` method receives three parameters: `type`, `data` and `options`, so your line: `$form = $this->createForm(SolutionsChooseType::class, $type);` should read:

```
$form = $this->createForm(SolutionsChooseType::class, $data, [
    'choices' => array_combine($types, $types),
]);
```

The [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) will assign the same `value` to each `option` as the text.

You can remove the `'choices' => array_flip($options['data']),` line from your `SolutionsChooseType`, as you'll be passing them from the controller.

Alternatively, you can move the setup done in the controller to the type itself, merging any options passed from the controller with your defaults.

Still in the form type, `FormEvent` callbacks get passed the event as the first argument and the underlying data as the second, so you have a chance to modify it; in your case that's a string.

You have two options here:

- Since you are adding an `EntityType` field, you can use the [`query_builder`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) option inside it. That will pass an `EntityRepository` for the class that you can use to populate your options (you have to return a `QueryBuilder`, not the `choices` themselves):

```
function (FormEvent $event) {
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

    $form->add('services', EntityType::class, [
        'class'       => Service::class,
        'placeholder' => 'Choisissez un type de service',
        'query_builder' => function($repository) use ($data) {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
                              ->where('u.Type = :type')
                              ->setParameter('type', $data);
        },
    ]);
}
```

- Inject and `EntityManager` (or `App\Repository\ServiceRepository` directly) into your parent type and use it in the Form modifier function. You'll have access to the [parent scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
class SolutionsChooseType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    // Code and listener setup ommited

    function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        $services = $this->em->getRepository(Service::class)->findBy([
            'Type' => $data,
        ]);

        $form->add('services', EntityType::class, [
            'class'       => Service::class,
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez un type de service',
            'choices'     => $services,
         ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @msg, I'll try this !

Comment: Well, I have to admit I said a little bit too quickly that "selected type is correctly passed by variable data".

OK, I'm writing an alert('data') in the js part of my view and the pop-up correctly shows the selected type BUT when I'm writing a var_dump($data) in SolutionsChooseType.php, it shows me entire array of types :-(

So, maybe something went wrong between ajax and my SolutionsChooseType.php... (regarding the url ???). url parameter is supposed to be the Route to Controller, not to Type, right ? (I think there is nothing to do with Routes in Types..)

Comment: @PierreErnould I'm not sure I understand... you get the `choices` or the whole (parent) form data? In `PRE_SET_DATA` you should get an array with the submitted values for the whole object. If you want only the `type` you should attach the listener to that field: `$builder->get('type')->addEventListener(...)`. Also, your javascript might be sendind the wrong data, I think you want `var data = $(this).val();` or `var data = $(this).children("option:selected").val();`, it should return the same thing.

Comment: I want to retrieve the type selected in 1st dropdown ; Then I use this type to search in my DB the services who have this type; Then  I want to inject those services in the 2nd dropdown

Comment: @PierreErnould After reading your question again more carefully I spotted a problem in the controller, I've mended my answer. As I could not try this, let me know if there's any other error.

Comment: There are still something wrong

The very first issue to me is about the url parameter in $.ajax: does it have to lead to the Controller .php or the Type.php ?

If I follow the symfony doc example, they write $form.attr('action') for url parameter and if I'm doin a console.log($form.attr('action'))  it shows undefined. And in fact, it seems quite obvious to me because there's no Action in my form. 

So where does this url parameter have to lead ?

Comment: @PierreErnould You had `/solution/all` hardcoded in your script, that's the same route as your controller. By default, if no `action` attribute is specified, the form is submitted to the current url. I'd however point it to a different controller action that returns the service entries and add them to the form.

Comment: I'm quite close to the end: I had to mend my code a bit (I'll write it down in an answer). The fact is that formModifier and addEventListener are totally useless to do what I want !! Now I can retrieve  type choosen by Ajax and it's correctly sent to my controller (thanks @msg: a different controller action was the solution)- But inside my controller, when I trying to call my ServiceRepository->findBy, it returns only keys (0, 1, 2..)

Comment: I got it !!! I had to add magic __toString() function to my ServiceEntity. Many many many thanks to @msg for help, ideas !!

Comment: @PierreErnould yes, besides `__toString` you could use the [`choice_label` form option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label) if you need `__toString` for other purposes.